# Find percentage of set of values in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
business_id  FP   count 
business_1    1    20
business_1    0    100
business_2    0    50
```

I want to calculate the percentage for every business_id having FP=1. Basically I need a value which is equal to count(where business_id=some id and FP=1)/count(where business_id=same_id and FP=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the value is always <1> my quick 2 cents would be:

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['business_1', 1, 20],
    ['business_1', 0, 100],
    ['business_2', 0, 50],
], columns=['business_id', 'FP', 'count'])
```

Calculate the percentages and return them as a dict with:

```
percentages = df.groupby('business_id').agg({
    'FP': ['count', 'sum']
})
(percentages[('FP', 'sum')] / percentages[('FP', 'count')]).to_dict()
```

Comment: @Divya Khiani - did that help?

Comment: with slight modification I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thanks !